# Composite simpson rule code keep getting wrong output?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, calculus

Algorthim:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ggs7.png)

I am trying to implement this composite Simpson rule that will calculate the following integral: 1/sqrt(x) which should result in: 2

However, I keep getting the wrong output such as 1.61663

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double f(double n)
{

    return 1/sqrt(n);
}

double simpson(double a, double b, double n)
{

double x0=f(a)+f(b);
double h=(b-a)/(n);
double x1=0,x2=0;
double x=0;
for(int i = 1 ; i <n;i++){
        x=a+(i*h);
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            x2=x2+f(x);
        }
        else
        {
            x1=x1+f(x);
        }
    }
        x1=(h*(x0+2*x2+4*x1))/3;
        return x1;
}

 int main(){

            cout<<"Integral is: "<<" "<<simpson(0.0004,1,20)<<" "<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: Didn't you forget to initialize some variables like `x1` and `x2`?

Comment: they are initialized to 0 by default

Comment: No. Only global ones are initialized by zeroing.

Comment: Done but still same output

Comment: Shouldn't x0 be initialized to `f(a) + f(b)` instead of multiplying the values?

Comment: It seems to me that the formula you used for the Simpson rule is different to the formula presented at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule)? Please add a source for the formula you want to implement.

Comment: @BlueTune done not form wikipedia

Comment: `1/sqrt(x)` diverges as `x -> 0`. 20 points are not enough to get a meaningful result. Try `2000` points. `simpson(0.0004,1,2000) = 1.96018`, which is pretty close to the exact value `1.96`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in your code, but in the function you're trying to integrate. This function diverges to infinity as `x` goes to zero. The derivatives also diverge.

For the interval `[a, 1]` with small `a`, the error term is bounded by `O[1/(N^4 a^4.5)]`. That's why to calculate the integral over this interval, the grid should be very dense to get a reasonable error bound.

`simpson(0.0004, 1, N)` produces the following values:

```
N      Result         Error
--------------------------------
20     2.549041009    0.5890
200    1.986462457    0.0265
2000   1.960181808    1.8181e-4
20000  1.960000049    4.9374e-8 
200000 1.960000000    5.0810e-12
```

And indeed, for large `N` we are getting closer and closer to the exact value `1.96` with the error `O(1/N^4)`.

Comment: what about this : simpson(0.0000001,1,2000000) its even more accurate

Comment: @sanjep, the error bound contains fourth derivative, that also diverges. The smaller `a`, the denser grid you need.

Comment: @sanjep, subtracted `1.96` from the result.